# Run both Apache with mod_wsgi and Nginx with Gunicorn on same server?

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, django, flask

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean that I'm using to host projects and learn about different technology.  I already have a couple of things running using Apache2 and mod_wsgi running a Flask app.  I'm interested in trying out some other things, specifically a Django app with Nginx and Gunicorn.

The various tutorials I've looked at all recommend starting with a fresh Ubuntu server, but I don't want to wipe my server; I'd like to keep hosting my existing projects.

Is it possible to set up all of this stuff on a single server without causing problems?  If so, I don't need a walkthrough, because I'll probably learn more figuring it out as I go but, if it isn't possible, I'd rather not throw away hours of time trying to make it work when it never will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the project, but yes you can absolutely host many multiple projects on one server. It is a great learning exercise, but there are a few considerations.

1. Make sure they are secured. One security breach can bring them all down.

   Only one service can exist on one port.

   Make sure the projects don't consume too much cpu, or it will bog all of them down.

   Docker containers could help host some projects in containers on the same server to avoid having configuration files clash and be overwritten if your projects are very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the additional pointers.  It seems I have plenty of work to do!

Comment: Good luck! I started out ten years ago with a dual core atom book sized pc... that is still sitting on my desk right now! It hosts a webpage and all my projects that I like to play with. I have since went to college for Linux System Administration, and have become a Linux System Administrator at a local business! It's an awesome journey if you enjoy this stuff, as I do.